# SQL Stored Procedure preventing to write null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

So, I've got this below implemented in one of my stored procedures.
And if they have less points as specified it works correctly but if they have normal points (not less) and they are for example level 61 and with 482 points total then the script will try to write NULL on total Points and I want to make it, so it wont do it and if they are okay with points just to do nothing. (like the script has never been executed) because if they have enough points then we dont have to add them.

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[REPAIR_USER_STAT_POINTS]    Script Date: 05/30/2013 03:57:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[REPAIR_USER_STAT_POINTS]

@strUserID varchar(21)

AS

DECLARE @Level int, @Point int, @Class int,@NewPoint int, @Strong int, @Sta int, @Dex int, @Intel int, @Cha int, @Total int



SELECT @Level = Level, @Class = Class, @Point = Points, @Strong = Strong, @Sta = Sta, @Dex = Dex, @Intel = Intel, @Cha = Cha FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = @strUserID

SET @Total = SUM(@Strong + @Sta + @Dex + @Intel + @Cha + @Point)


IF @Level = 61 AND @Total < 482

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 10

END

IF @Level = 62 AND @Total < 487

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 15

END

IF @Level = 63 AND @Total < 492

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 20

END

IF @Level = 64 AND @Total < 497

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 25

END

IF @Level = 65 AND @Total < 502

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 30

END

IF @Level = 66 AND @Total < 507

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 35

END

IF @Level = 67 AND @Total < 512

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 40

END

IF @Level = 68 AND @Total < 517

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 45

END

IF @Level = 69 AND @Total < 522

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 50

END

IF @Level = 70 AND @Total < 527

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 55

END

IF @Level = 71 AND @Total < 532

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 60

END

IF @Level = 72 AND @Total < 537

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 65

END

IF @Level = 73 AND @Total < 542

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 70

END

IF @Level = 74 AND @Total < 547

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 75

END

IF @Level = 75 AND @Total < 552

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 80

END

IF @Level = 76 AND @Total < 557

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 85

END

IF @Level = 77 AND @Total < 562

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 90

END

IF @Level = 78 AND @Total < 567

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 95

END

IF @Level = 79 AND @Total < 572

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 100

END

IF @Level = 80 AND @Total < 577

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 105

END

IF @Level = 81 AND @Total < 582

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 110

END

IF @Level = 82 AND @Total < 587

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 115

END

IF @Level = 83 AND @Total < 592

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 120

END



IF @Class = 201 OR @Class = 205 OR @Class = 206 OR @Class = 101 OR @Class = 105 OR @Class = 106

BEGIN

UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '247',Dex = '60',Sta = '65',Intel = '50',Cha = '50',Points = @NewPoint WHERE strUserId = @strUserId

END

ELSE IF @Class = 202 OR @Class = 207 OR @Class = 208 OR @Class = 102 OR @Class = 107 OR @Class = 108

BEGIN

UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '60',Dex = '252',Sta = '60',Intel = '50',Cha = '50',Points = @NewPoint WHERE strUserId = @strUserId

END

ELSE IF @Class = 203 OR @Class = 209 OR @Class = 210 OR @Class = 103 OR @Class = 109 OR @Class = 110

BEGIN

UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '50',Dex = '70',Sta = '50',Intel = '70',Cha = '232',Points = @NewPoint WHERE strUserId = @strUserId

END

ELSE IF @Class = 204 OR @Class = 211 OR @Class = 212 OR @Class = 104 OR @Class = 111 OR @Class = 112

BEGIN

UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '65',Dex = '60',Sta = '65',Intel = '232',Cha = '50',Points = @NewPoint WHERE strUserId = @strUserId

END
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Did you leave out some of the script?

Comment: I just need to know how to make it if we dont meet the criteria above, so the script will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a CASE statement with an ELSE clause.  It's more concise anyway.

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[REPAIR_USER_STAT_POINTS]    Script Date: 05/30/2013 03:57:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[REPAIR_USER_STAT_POINTS]
@strUserID varchar(21)
AS
DECLARE @Level int, @Point int, @Class int,@NewPoint int, @Strong int, @Sta int, @Dex int, @Intel int, @Cha int, @Total int

SELECT @Level = Level, @Class = Class, @Point = Points, @Strong = Strong, @Sta = Sta, @Dex = Dex, @Intel = Intel, @Cha = Cha 
FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = @strUserID

SET @Total = SUM(@Strong + @Sta + @Dex + @Intel + @Cha + @Point)


SET @NewPoint = 
    CASE WHEN @Level = 61 AND @Total < 482 THEN 10
        WHEN @Level = 62 AND @Total < 487 THEN 15
        WHEN @Level = 63 AND @Total < 492 THEN 20
        WHEN @Level = 64 AND @Total < 497 THEN 25
        WHEN @Level = 65 AND @Total < 502 THEN 30
        WHEN @Level = 66 AND @Total < 507 THEN 35
        WHEN @Level = 67 AND @Total < 512 THEN 40
        WHEN @Level = 68 AND @Total < 517 THEN 45
        WHEN @Level = 69 AND @Total < 522 THEN 50
        WHEN @Level = 70 AND @Total < 527 THEN 55
        WHEN @Level = 71 AND @Total < 532 THEN 60
        WHEN @Level = 72 AND @Total < 537 THEN 65
        WHEN @Level = 73 AND @Total < 542 THEN 70
        WHEN @Level = 74 AND @Total < 547 THEN 75
        WHEN @Level = 75 AND @Total < 552 THEN 80
        WHEN @Level = 76 AND @Total < 557 THEN 85
        WHEN @Level = 77 AND @Total < 562 THEN 90
        WHEN @Level = 78 AND @Total < 567 THEN 95
        WHEN @Level = 79 AND @Total < 572 THEN 100
        WHEN @Level = 80 AND @Total < 577 THEN 105
        WHEN @Level = 81 AND @Total < 582 THEN 110
        WHEN @Level = 82 AND @Total < 587 THEN 115
        WHEN @Level = 83 AND @Total < 592 THEN 120
        ELSE @Point
    END


IF @Point <> @NewPoint
BEGIN
    IF @Class = 201 OR @Class = 205 OR @Class = 206 OR @Class = 101 OR @Class = 105 OR @Class = 106
    BEGIN
        UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '247',Dex = '60',Sta = '65',Intel = '50',Cha = '50',Points = @NewPoint 
        WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
    END
    ELSE IF @Class = 202 OR @Class = 207 OR @Class = 208 OR @Class = 102 OR @Class = 107 OR @Class = 108
    BEGIN
        UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '60',Dex = '252',Sta = '60',Intel = '50',Cha = '50',Points = @NewPoint 
        WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
    END
    ELSE IF @Class = 203 OR @Class = 209 OR @Class = 210 OR @Class = 103 OR @Class = 109 OR @Class = 110
    BEGIN
        UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '50',Dex = '70',Sta = '50',Intel = '70',Cha = '232',Points = @NewPoint 
        WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
    END
    ELSE IF @Class = 204 OR @Class = 211 OR @Class = 212 OR @Class = 104 OR @Class = 111 OR @Class = 112
    BEGIN
        UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '65',Dex = '60',Sta = '65',Intel = '232',Cha = '50',Points = @NewPoint 
        WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
    END
END
```

Comment: Hmmm. My code is checking the level and points, so If the points are less than it should be. It will add event numbers (@NewPoint).
My question is simple. If the are the required level and have the required points, not less .. the script should do nothing. I cant set it to 0 because it will add 0 event points and if they had before 30, it will reset them.

Comment: So do `ELSE @NewPoint` and just set it back to itself.  It's really the easiest way.

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near '@NewPoint'.` when I add ELSE @NewPoint

Comment: I've changed the answer to use @NewPoint as the else.

Comment: I want to use my procedure, so will this do the job: `ELSE IF @NewPoint = @NewPoint
BEGIN 
Set @NewPoint = @NewPoint
END`

Comment: When I have all the correct points, it disconnects me from game when I try to login and the log says: `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Points'` So, I want to avoid it to trying to insert NULL and just do nothing.

Comment: Yea when I was updating the SP I figured out what was going on.  If it falls through you want to set it to `@Point` since that is the original value.

Comment: You could of course have solved the problem by adding a `SET @NewPoint = @Point` to the very beginning of the SP and if it wasn't reset to anything else it would still be `@Point`.  This way is cleaner and easier to maintain though.

Comment: Hey now it works perfectly. Just want to ask you what was the cause of this issue ? Also, your script wont cause any security whole or such troubles, or overload right ?

Comment: The problem was that '@NewPoint' will default to NULL.  If you never set it then when you got to the update statement it would still be NULL.  If you set it to `@Point` (the original value) either before the whole thing, or after if it doesn't fit any other case then you are fixed.  This method has no security issues that aren't in the original and will in fact be slightly faster since the CASE statement will quit once it has an answer and not continue through a series of un-needed IF statements.

Comment: Tested it and there is one more issue. Now it works but the rest of the UPDATE code below is executing every time doesnt matter what. So is there a way to do it if its `ELSE @Point` to abort the code below too ?

Comment: If we can fix it, so when we have `ELSE @Point` (no updates required) then the below code wont get executed as well. I'll be really happy and grateful.

Comment: Can It be like that ? `IF @NewPoint = @Point
  RETURN` instead of `IF @Point <> @NewPoint
BEGIN`

Comment: Let me know please ? That's the final source: http://pastebin.com/Pj86E9Wg Let me know if it's correct. Also, what you mean by "This method has no security issues that aren't in the original" ? Waiting to find out and let me accept the answer.

Comment: What I mean is that neither `IF` or `CASE` have any effect on security.  And yes, you could use `IF @NewPoint = @Point RETURN` just as easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little confused by your question, but this should work as I understand.  Instead of all the `IF` statements, consider moving into a single `CASE` statement, defaulting the value to 0.  Then add a check if the value isn't 0, to do something.

```
DECLARE @Level int
DECLARE @Total int
DECLARE @NewPoint int

SET @Level = 61
SET @Total = 100

SELECT 
  @NewPoint = CASE
                WHEN @Level = 61 AND @Total < 482 THEN 10
                WHEN @Level = 62 AND @Total < 487 THEN 15
                WHEN @Level = 63 AND @Total < 492 THEN 20
                WHEN @Level = 64 AND @Total < 497 THEN 25
                WHEN @Level = 65 AND @Total < 502 THEN 30
                ELSE 0
              END

IF @NewPoint <> 0 
BEGIN
  SELECT 'DO SOMETHING'
END
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/14722)

Comment: Hmmm. My code is checking the level and points, so If the points are less than it should be. It will add event numbers (@NewPoint).
My question is simple. If the are the required level and have the required points, not less .. the script should do nothing.

Comment: @nLal -- what do you mean by do nothing.  In the above, no scripts are running -- we're just setting the NewPoint variable.  The IF statement should handle whether or not to run additional scripts.

Comment: Updated my first post with the complete stored procedure.
If they have the required points and not less, the script should do nothing.

Comment: @nLal -- Do you mean when the NewPoint variable does not get set, then you don't want to run the UPDATE statements?  If so, just add an IF statement as I did above and preset NewPoint to 0.  The CASE statement is a little bit cleaner than all those IF statements as well.

Comment: But wont NewPoint 0 set the points to 0 ?
Because if I have the required points by NewPoint 0 it will reset them to 0 I think ?

Comment: @nLal -- the IF statement will prevent the UPDATES from running if newpoint = 0.  The UPDATE statements will only run IF newpoint does not equal (<>) 0.

Comment: Can you check out my code and edit it as it should be, so if there are enough points and not < less, so it wont run anything and it wont update anything. Will be much appreciated. I'm asking for this favour because I dont want to screw it up .. it will be a huge loss. Thanks

Comment: Just to sum it up. Once the script see that I've got enough points, the `set @NetPoints` will be `NULL`, so when it enteres in the update query it will try to insert `MULL` and I just want to prevent this by doing nothing.

Comment: Can I just type after the set @NewPoints checks levels .. `ELSE IF  @NewPoints='NULL' END` ?
So, if there is nothing to update, it will do nothing istead of trying to insert `NULL` ?

Comment: `IF @NewPoint = NULL
BEGIN
SET @NewPoint = 0
END` Something like this but to avoid updating the newpoint to 0

Comment: When I have all the correct points, it disconnects me from game when I try to login and the log says: `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Points'` So, I want to avoid it to trying to insert NULL and just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly you could modify the ELSE.

**Change From:**

```
ELSE @NewPoint = @NewPoint
```

**Change To:**

```
ELSE return
```

This will abort the script and no updates will occur.

Comment: If they dont meet the required criteria for less points, correctly ? Basically if they have enough points and not less the script will just abort without updating anything, correctly ?

Comment: Tested it. Now even if I have less points they wont update .... So basically now it doesnt work

Comment: Explain what you want to do if there are less points. You have probably explained it in your original question, but if you explain in constructively in your comment you're more likely to get a solution.

Comment: and _AT LEAST_ make an effort to close this question before posting a new one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826342/sql-stored-procedure-preventing-to-write-null

Comment: @ElectricLlama: The correct thing here is to close this one as a duplicate of the one you linked, as it was asked first. The poster should edit that question instead. I've flagged this one for the moderators (asking them to merge them) and voted to close this one already for that reason.